# How to compare consecutive date/time items in array and filter based on a specific time

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have the following array of objects:

```
var transactions = [
[
    {"id":1,"sourceAccount":"A","targetAccount":"B","amount":100,"category":"food","time":"2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z"},
    {"id":2,"sourceAccount":"A","targetAccount":"B","amount":100,"category":"food","time":"2018-03-02T10:33:50.000Z"},
    {"id":3,"sourceAccount":"A","targetAccount":"B","amount":100,"category":"food","time":"2018-03-02T10:34:30.000Z"},
    {"id":4,"sourceAccount":"A","targetAccount":"B","amount":100,"category":"food","time":"2018-03-02T10:36:00.000Z"}
],
[
    {"id":5,"sourceAccount":"A","targetAccount":"C","amount":250,"category":"other","time":"2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z"},
    {"id":6,"sourceAccount":"A","targetAccount":"C","amount":250,"category":"other","time":"2018-03-02T10:33:05.000Z"}
]
]
```

I need to compare `time` property of each object consecutively, and keep only those properties which time difference between each consecutive transaction is less than 1 minute.

The array format should be stay same, this is what I did try, but no luck, didn't work. What's the problem?

```
 var newArray = transactions.map(g => g.reduce((r, o, i, a) => {
        if (!i || new Date(o.time).getTime() - new Date(a[i - 1].time).getTime() >= 60000) {
            r.push([o]);
        } else {
            r[r.length - 1].push(o);
        }
        return r;
    }, []));
```

The expected output is something like this :

```
var output = [
[
    {"id":1,"sourceAccount":"A","targetAccount":"B","amount":100,"category":"food","time":"2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z"},
    {"id":2,"sourceAccount":"A","targetAccount":"B","amount":100,"category":"food","time":"2018-03-02T10:33:50.000Z"},
    {"id":3,"sourceAccount":"A","targetAccount":"B","amount":100,"category":"food","time":"2018-03-02T10:34:30.000Z"}
],
[
    {"id":5,"sourceAccount":"A","targetAccount":"C","amount":250,"category":"other","time":"2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z"},
    {"id":6,"sourceAccount":"A","targetAccount":"C","amount":250,"category":"other","time":"2018-03-02T10:33:05.000Z"}
]
]
```

Comment: Please can you elaborate, what you are trying achieve or the rule which your expected output follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `Array#map` your source array, and in each iteration, `Array#filter` the desired elements by comparing the time of current element with the time of previous element.

```js
var transactions = [[{"id":1,"sourceAccount":"A","targetAccount":"B","amount":100,"category":"food","time":"2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z"},{"id":2,"sourceAccount":"A","targetAccount":"B","amount":100,"category":"food","time":"2018-03-02T10:33:50.000Z"},{"id":3,"sourceAccount":"A","targetAccount":"B","amount":100,"category":"food","time":"2018-03-02T10:34:30.000Z"},{"id":4,"sourceAccount":"A","targetAccount":"B","amount":100,"category":"food","time":"2018-03-02T10:36:00.000Z"}],[{"id":5,"sourceAccount":"A","targetAccount":"C","amount":250,"category":"other","time":"2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z"},{"id":6,"sourceAccount":"A","targetAccount":"C","amount":250,"category":"other","time":"2018-03-02T10:33:05.000Z"}]];

var result = transactions.map((tr, i) => {
  return tr.filter((t, j) => {
    if (transactions[i][j - 1]) {
      var d1 = new Date(t.time);
      var d2 = new Date(transactions[i][j - 1].time);
      return (d1.getTime() - d2.getTime()) <= 60000;
    }

    return true;
  });
});

console.log(result);
```